# Big query unnest array with json values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Lets consider the following table on Google BigQuery:

```
WITH example AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, ["{\"id\":1, \"name\":\"AAA\"}", "{\"id\":2, \"name\":\"BBB\"}","{\"id\":3, \"name\":\"CCC\"}"] 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, ["{\"id\":5, \"name\":\"XXX\"}", "{\"id\":6, \"name\":\"ZZZ\"}"] 
)
SELECT * 
FROM example;
```

[image]

I would like to compose a query that will return names with their parent row's id.

like:

[image]

I tried using unnest with json functions and I just cant make this right.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks
Ido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your query, you already have json elements in your array. So with the use of unnest, you can use a [json function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data#query_json_data) like `json_value` to extract the name attribute of your elements.

```sql
select 
    id,
    json_value(elt, '$.name')
from example, unnest(r) as elt;
```